# Magento 2 : How to forward controller defaultNoRoute?

Tags: magento2, 404-page, 404, noroute

I create a custom module in which if data is found the template is shown else I need to show default 404-page content & set the status to 404.

I have tried below code to set the status to 404 without changing the URL(i.e, not redirecting to noroute)

```
$resultPage->setStatusHeader(404, '1.1', 'Page Not Found');
$resultPage->setHeader('Status', '404 Page Not Found');
```

But I'm unable to show the default 404 error page content.

I have tried below code to forward the controller to default no route page, but it's not working for me.

```
$this->_forward('defaultNoRoute');
```

Can anyone help me out from this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this class for redirection**

```
public function __construct
(
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $forwardFactory
) 
{
    $this->_forwardFactory = $forwardFactory;
}
```

**Now you can redirect to 404 page using this**

```
if(CONDITION)
{
    $resultForward = $this->_forwardFactory->create();
    $resultForward->setController('index');
    $resultForward->forward('defaultNoRoute');
    return $resultForward;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You Can Override `Magento\Framework\App\Router\NoRouteHandlerList` File In `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml`

**And You Can Add Your Code Like This :-**

```
public function execute()
    {
        $resultLayout = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultLayout->setStatusHeader(404, '1.1', 'Not Found');
        $resultLayout->setHeader('Status', '404 File not found');
        return $resultLayout;
    }
```

**Reference Link**

[Create custom 404 page for not-found products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/116758/72911)